# Alternative to PuTTY Connection Manager?

Tags: putty, window-manager

Development of the free application [Putty Connection Manager](http://puttycm.free.fr/cms/) that can display more than one Putty sessions stopped in 2009, and it sometimes triggers this error when I double-click on any host in the right hand-side list:

```
PuTTY Connection Manager/An unexpected error occured : 

Object reference not set to an instance of an object..
```

When that happens, I have to reboot :-/

Does someone know of an alternative?

Comment: About this error, you just need to tick the options : "Show tray icon when minimized" and you won't see this error anymore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SuperPuTTY works great and I've moved over to it. Also check out KiTTY, an 'improved' PuTTY:

http://code.google.com/p/superputty/

http://www.9bis.net/kitty/

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Apparently, unlike Putty Connection Manager, SuperPutty requires creating new items in its Putty Sessions list, but it's easy enough.

Comment: Yes, you have to redo all your connections, but new ones appear immediately in the list.

Comment: I guess SuperPutty is based on Putty Connection Manager, and suffers from the same issues (ALT-TABbing to it doesn't work very well, and CTRL-TAB doesn't work to move around open windows within SuperPutty).

Comment: Superputty doesn't save username/pass or have login macros :(

Comment: Just a few updates, SuperPutty (as of 1.3.0.11) now incorporates fixes for some of the above issues. Note that I'm testing with KiTTY, but Alt-Tab now lets you resume typing in the PuTTY window, and Ctrl-Tab changes tabs left-to-right. As for username/pass, I've found a better solution is public/private keys with Pageant. Login macros are missing, although you can supply a script file to run in PuTTY via -m path/to/file.