# Software to manage SSH connections

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, ssh

Do you know a program for managing SSH connections?

I used [mRemote](http://www.mremote.org/wiki/) and [PuTTY Connection Manager](http://techie-buzz.com/softwares/putty-connection-manager-get-tabbed-putty-interface.HTML), but I'm looking for other (better) software for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to https://superuser.com/questions/230582/looking-for-an-alternative-to-putty-on-windows and [Alternative to PuTTY Connection Manager?](https://superuser.com/questions/255990/alternative-to-putty-connection-manager-closed)

Comment: Sorry I didn't found this questions...